# Witten's description of WZW conformal blocks

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I am reading this paper by Witten - [Geometric Langlands From Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2720.pdf). In section 4.1, he gives a description of the vector space of conformal blocks of the current algebra associated to a simply-laced and simply-connected Lie Group $G$ at level 1. He claims that on a Riemann Surface $W$, this vector space is the Heisenberg representation of the Heisenberg group associated to $H^1 (W, \mathcal{Z})$ where $\mathcal{Z} = \pi_1 (G)$. Later he shows that the dimension of this vector space is $(\#\mathcal{Z})^g$, which I have checked indeed coincides with the dimension computed through e.g. the Verlinde formula.

**My questions are as follows** - (1) What is the reason behind the appearance of $H^1 (W, \mathcal{Z})$ in this context?

(2) Does the vector space of conformal blocks have an interpretation in terms of a Heisenberg group associated to a cohomology group when the level is not equal to 1?

P.S. [I have asked the same question on Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/517812/wittens-description-of-wzw-conformal-blocks) in case that is important.